# Passing a class's properties to class method selectively in Swift

Tags: swift, class, methods, parameters

```
struct Bar
{
    var one:[Int] = []
    var two:[Int] = []
    var tri:[Int] = []
}

class foo
{
    var bar = Bar()

    func setupBar()
    {
        bar.one = [1]
        bar.two = [2,2]
        bar.tri = [3,3,3]
    }

    //bars are updated here
    func updateBars()
    {
        updateBar(bar.one, bar.two) //...here...
        updateBar(bar.two, bar.tri) //...here...
        //etc...
    }

    //Bar1 should be concatenated with Bar2, and thus Bar1 will be updated.
    func updateBar(_bar1:[Int], _bar2:[Int]) //...here...
    {

    }
```

In the above example, what is the correct syntax for parameters of updateBar method in both definition and calling?

I tried using inout, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track of using `inout`, just do not forget to have an `&`, at calling.

So, declare the function like this:

```
func updateBar(_ bar1: inout [Int], _ bar2:[Int])
```

And call like this:

```
updateBar(&bar.one, bar.two)
```

I've also put some code:

```
struct Bar
{
    var one:[Int] = []
    var two:[Int] = []
    var tri:[Int] = []
}

class foo
{
    var bar = Bar()

    func setupBar()
    {
        bar.one = [1]
        bar.two = [2,2]
        bar.tri = [3,3,3]
    }

    //bars are updated here
    func updateBars()
    {
        updateBar(&bar.one, bar.two) //...here...
        updateBar(&bar.two, bar.tri) //...here...
    }

    //Bar1 should be concatenated with Bar2, and thus Bar1 will be updated.
    func updateBar(_ bar1: inout [Int], _ bar2:[Int]) //...here...
    {
        bar1.append(contentsOf: bar2)
    }
}

let f = foo()
f.setupBar()
f.updateBars()
```

Comment: If you put an explanation of what you have done in your answer, you'll get my upvote.

Comment: @JeremyP, you are right. An explanation is good to have, than just plain code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Function parameters have an *argument label* and a *parameter name*. If you don't specify an *argument label* the calling function must use the *parameter name* to specify the parameter. So if you define

```
func updateBar(bar1:[Int], bar2:[Int]){}
```

you have to call your function like so:

```
updateBar(bar1: bar.one, bar2: bar.two)
# in your case you should have called updateBar(_bar1: bar.one, _bar2: bar.two)
```

If you want to omit the *argument label* in the calling function, you should explicitly mark it as omitted using `_`:

```
func updateBar(_ bar1: [Int], _ bar2: [Int]){}  # note space between _ and bar1
```

Now you can call your function without argument labels:

```
updateBar(bar.one, bar.two)
```